# Unable to reach specific sites

Tags: networking, dns, browser

Recently I've tried to setup a modded minecraft server and I ran into the isue that I can't reach minecraftforge.net. All I get is that the site is unreachable and that it took to long for the site to respond. I've checked https://isitdownorjustme.net/ to rule out the possibility of the site being down as I know for a fact that I've been able to reach the site in the past.

After that I've taken the following steps to try and find the issue:

- Tried it on other browsers (chrome incognito, firefox and edge. all with the same result)
- Tried it on other devices (laptop, phone)
- Checked if it was being blocked by pihole
- Changed the pc/router DNS (to skip the pihole completely)
- Tried pinging the site directly
- Tried resetting the router to factory settings

During these steps I've noticed that the request doesn't even appear in the pihole's request history, as if there never was a request to visit the site.
Having tried all these troubleshooting steps, I've run out of ideas of what the culprit could be.

Any help with this would be appriciated.